# Powershell test-path then remove-item but file in use by another process

Tags: powershell

I'm using Powershell for some file manipulation and performing the following steps:

1. Copy a file from one location to another (copy-item)
2. Verify that the new file is where it's expected (test-path)
3. If verified in the new location, remove the original (remove-item)

This process works 99.9% of the time but sometimes I'm receiving an error when the remove-item step occurs informing me that the original file is already in use / locked.  I can only assume that the process using this is the copy-item / test-path from steps 1 or 2.

Do I need to instruct Powershell to wait until the copy-item / test-path are finished before proceeding with the remove-item?  Or is it more likely that there is another process running somewhere else such as on access AV that is causing this problem?  If so, is there a method of easily retrying in the event of a file lock being in place?

Here is part of the code that performs the steps mentioned:

```
if ($copySuccess = "TRUE") {
    $wiFiles = Get-ChildItem $xmlDir -Filter $itemNum*.*
    $wiFiles | ForEach-Object {
        if ($copySuccess -eq "TRUE") {
            Copy-Item -LiteralPath $xmlDir\$_ -Destination $processedDir
                if (!(Test-Path -LiteralPath $processedDir\$_)) {
                    $copySuccess = "FALSE"
                }
            } 
        }
    }                    
    if ($copySuccess -eq "TRUE") {
        Get-ChildItem $xmlDir -Filter $itemNum*.* | Remove-Item
    }
```

The files being moved are small text files or image files <1MB and typically <10 files per itemNum.

Thanks, Rob.

Comment: Where's the script itself?  We would need to see at least a [mcve] in order to validate why there could be a lock on a file.

Comment: `Copy-Item` is synchronous so it's unlikely to be the culprit. An AV or other software that scans the filesystem (maybe an indexer, sync software if it's in a google drive/dropbox/skydrive folder) is more likely. To determine what you have to do, you have to figure out what's locking it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is very unlikely that your cmdlets are causing the problem. if you want to make sure each cmdlet finishes before the next starts wrap each command in

```
$job1 = Start-Job { [Powershell code] }
Wait-Job $job1
```

For the delete command you could try something along the lines of

```
While ( Test-Path($yourFileDir) ){
    Try{
        remove-item [your item] -ErrorAction Stop
    }catch{
        Write-Verbose "File locked, trying again in 5"
        Start-Sleep -seconds 5
    }
}
```

Of course, you can tidy this up to fit your needs, adding an appropriate time out etc.

Comment: Flash, that code looks like it should fit the bill nicely thanks!  Will try and update.  Cheers, Rob.

Comment: @RobBerry, how did it go? Did running the tasks as jobs solve the issue or the while statement or did you need both? I may be doing something similar soon and would like to know how you got on.

Comment: Hi Flash, I had a quick test earlier, but had issues as the catch wasn't triggered following an error with the remove-item.  Needs to do some testing tomorrow but will let you know.  Rgds,Rob.

Comment: Hi Flash_Steel, got the code working with the catch, just needed to add -ErrorAction Stop following the remove-item to enable the catch to trigger.  Thanks for the assistance, Rob.

Comment: That's great. I have updated the answer so it works properly.

Comment: is there a more formal way to test if an item is locked / in-use than a try/catch like this ?

Comment: @orionelenzil - The problem with doing a check then executing code, rather than executing code in a try/catch, is that the result is only true for the instant the check is performed. You would still need to execute the code afterwards in a try/catch after testing.